# Why base.pm is not visible on file list on github?

Tags: perl, github

If you go by link:
https://github.com/Perl/perl5/tree/blead/lib

You will not find `base.pm` file

[image]

But If you clone this repo locally `base.pm` will be found at `lib/base.pm`

Why `base.pm` is not visible on the github?

**UPD**

```
kes@work ~/work/projects/github-forks/perl-hub/lib $ git tree | head -n 5
* 320f4ba290 (HEAD -> blead, upstream/blead) Sync DB_File with CPAN version 1.856
*   415da10787 Merge branch '18780-compound-token-split-by-macro' into blead
|\  
| * 7169efc775 skip using gcc brace groups for STMT_START/END
|/  

kes@work ~/work/projects/github-forks/perl-hub/lib $ git remote -v
upstream    hub:Perl/perl5 (fetch)
upstream    hub:Perl/perl5 (push)
```

where `hub` is configured to `github.com` via `.ssh/config`:

```
host    hub
        user git
        hostname github.com
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        port 22
```

Comment: Strange. It doesn't appear in forks either, so it's not just the `Perl/perl5` repo.

Comment: In an unrelated repo (not even a Perl project), I created a file called `lib/base.pm` and committed it. It did get displayed. So it's not a filename Github is treating specially.

Comment: @tobyink: it is just clone of `github.com/Perl/perl5` repo and `git checkout blead`. See updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the perl distribution, that file exists as dist/base/lib/base.pm. It is copied to lib/base.pm as part of the build process

Comment: But I just clone repository, I did not build anything yet. And I have `lib/base.pm`. Anyway thank you for hint where I can find this file.

Comment: Is this probably hard link?

Comment: It's not a link, hard nor sort. It's a copy, and it's copied as part of the build process. It is not in the repository: try 'git ls-files | grep base.pm'.

Comment: If it is copied why this file is not displayed as `untracket file` by `git status`? Also `git log lib/base.pm` show commit history for this file.

Comment: It's not displayed by 'git status' because it has an entry in lib/.gitignore. It shows up in 'git log lib/base.pm' because 12 years ago it did indeed live under lib/. That last commit shows it being moved from lib/